# Filter in csv using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv to import in the power shell, I can import the file with the command:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'c:/.../etc' -Delimiter ","
```

And perform some simple filters like this:

```
$b = "Date development"
$a| Where {$_.$b -l '11/06/2021'} | Format-Table
```

Given this, I would like to know how I would filter an interval between date stamps. The formatting would be:

```
Name, development date, ID  --- Headers
P0113D, 10/06/2021,33  
P0123D, 4/16/2020, 42  
P0423D, 10/25/2021, 213  
P0113D, 11/22/2021, 298
```

I would like to import the Date Range from 10/06/2021 to 10/25/2021 29 and export the filtered file.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do it like this, note that, we're using `$_.'development date' -as [datetime]`, this will convert the current values on the `development date` column, which are `strings`, to a [`datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0) object.

In this example, it is filtering a range between `10/06/2021` and `10/25/2021` including both dates.

```
@'
Name, development date, ID
P0113D, 10/06/2021,33  
P0123D, 4/16/2020, 42  
P0423D, 10/25/2021, 213  
P0113D, 11/22/2021, 298
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | Where-Object {
    $date = $_.'development date' -as [datetime]
    $date -ge [datetime]'10/06/2021' -and $date -le [datetime]'10/25/2021'
}
```

**Output:**

```
Name   development date ID
----   ---------------- --
P0113D 10/06/2021       33 
P0423D 10/25/2021       213
```

Note that, the above is there as an example, if you're trying it out from a `CSV` file the syntax would be:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'c:/.../etc' -Delimiter "," | Where-Object { ....
```

---

To clarify on the difference between using `-as` and casting `[datetime]` to the string, here is a practical example:

```
[datetime]'11/22/2021'       # => Monday, November 22, 2021 12:00:00 AM
'11/22/2021' -as [datetime]  # => Monday, November 22, 2021 12:00:00 AM
[datetime]'notadate!!!'      # => Exception thrown
'notadate!!!' -as [datetime] # => Nothing is returned // no errors
```

Comment: That was it ! Thank you very much !

Comment: @Ashurayaz happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Please change the snip below to match your date range. Any issues please respond. Thanks.

```
Import-Csv -Path 'c:/.../etc' -Delimiter ","

$filterDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)

$Data = Import-CSV "H:\Data.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Date -as [datetime] -lt $filterDate}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time.